# Microsoft Service Fabric and logging

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core, azure-service-fabric

I am investigating the best way to implement logging for my Service Fabric Stateless API and have been somewhat overwhelmed by the varying different solutions for what appears to be a relatively simple requirement.

I have implemented logging using the `WebHostBuilder().ConfigureLogging` and have successfully logged my trace messages to the Debug window and via `Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File` I have also managed to dump this log to a file, this all being controlled via a `#if DEBUG` directive and this I was happy with.

Then I needed to configure what would happen when deployed to a cluster within Azure and this is when I became overwhelmed!!!

I thought that I could register `ServiceEventSource` type logger in the same manner as I did with `AddDebug` however it was not this simple.

So I have managed to get my logs to appear within the diagnostic window using the `ServiceEventSource.Current.Message` but these logs are not integrated within the ASP.NET logging framework :/

My continued investigation has led me to understand that Service Fabric logging should be directed towards Application Insights albeit many, many articles having varying degrees of detail and applicability to the latest framework.

My current thinking is that I need to remove the ASP.NET logging and implement something such as `EventFlow` to allow my trace messages to be generated and subsequently piped through to Application Insights for interrogation at a later date, is my thinking correct??

Or am I currently going off at a tangent?

Comment: Do you need the local dump? Given that you'd be debugging, you'll have immediate access to the code, would you be ok with pumping the local data to AI as well?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I think I have a solution coming together using Serilog integrated with the ```Microsoft.Extensions.Logging``` package. I'm amazed at how little documentation exists around this subject with regards real world implementations.  Once I have got this all working I will document my process and the tools I've used to bring things together it might help somebody else in the future.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger You should be able use this doc to enable application insights to capture all ILogger based logs.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE 15/05/2019**
After deploying this to Azure Service Fabric the log files were not populated, this appears to be an incompatibility between the `Serilog.Sinks.AzureBlobStorage` NUGET package and the .NET Core version 2.2.0 that my project was targeting.

I have posted a ticket on the GitHub page and await a response, in the short term you can download the source code and migrate the project to a `Microsoft.NETCore.App` 2.2.0 project and directly reference this and everything works perfectly.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**
I seem to do this quite a lot, answering my own question but here goes again.  It's taken me a day or two to get to the bottom of this so I thought I would share my findings and solution with the community in-case it might help somebody else in the future and/or somebody might have something to add or even contradict me which I'd welcome any input.

My development environment is as follows: -

`Microsoft Visual Studio 15.9.11`
`Windows 10 Professional`
SDK: `Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.0`

I created a new Service Fabric Stateless Service the purpose of this service is to provide RESTful endpoints to a Angular 7 front end web application.

My requirement was to provide logging information in both my development environment via the Debug window and to also provide similar logging information whilst my apps are being hosted within a Service Fabric Cluster on Azure.

**NUGET Package Installations**
`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging (2.2.0)`
`Serilog.AspNetCore (2.1.1)`
`Serilog.Enrichers.Environment (2.1.3)`
`Serilog.Settings.Configuration (3.0.1)`
`Serilog.Sinks.Debug (1.0.1)`
`Serilog.Sinks.AzureBlobStorage (1.3.0)`

**Controlling Development & Production Environments**
I control the development & production environments using the `DEBUG` pre-processor directive to include either the `appsettings.json` or `appsettings.Development.json` file.

My appSettings.Development.json file is like this: -

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
     // My app settings not applicable to this
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Debug" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Verbose",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Debug",
        "Args": {
          "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {MachineName} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": ["WithMachineName"]
  } 
}
```

My appSettings.json file is like this: -

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
     // My app settings not applicable to this
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.AzureBlobStorage" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "AzureBlobStorage",
        "Args": {
          "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {MachineName} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "connectionString": "[Connection String]",
          "storageContainerName": "app",
          "storageFileName": "{yyyy}-{MM}-{dd}.log"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "WithMachineName" ]
  }
}
```

As you can see from the above settings files I output to the Debug window when in development and I have chosen to output to Azure Blob Storage when deployed to a Service Fabric Cluster in Azure.

To implement the Serilog logging simple review my Stateless Service class implementation below, which shows how to toggle the two different appSettings.json files dependent upon the environment and also how the Serilog logger is inserted into the dependency injection system via the use of the `UseSerilog` extension method.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Fabric;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.Runtime;
using Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Runtime;
using Serilog;

namespace Caboodal.Manatee.ServiceFabric.Api.Identity
{
    internal sealed class Identity : StatelessService
    {
        public Identity(StatelessServiceContext context)
            : base(context)
        {
        }

        private string AppSettingsFilename
        {
            get
            {
#if DEBUG
                return "appsettings.Development.json";
#else
                return "appsettings.json";
#endif
            }
        }

        protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
        {
            var appSettings = GetAppSettings();

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(appSettings)
                .CreateLogger();

            return new[]
            {
                new ServiceInstanceListener(
                    serviceContext =>
                        new KestrelCommunicationListener(
                            serviceContext,
                            "ServiceEndpoint",
                            (url, listener) =>
                            {
                                ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(serviceContext, $"Starting Kestrel on {url}");

                                return new WebHostBuilder()
                                    .UseKestrel()
                                    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(
                                        (builderContext, config) =>
                                        {
                                            config.AddJsonFile(AppSettingsFilename, false, true);
                                        })
                                    .ConfigureServices(
                                        services => services
                                            .AddSingleton(serviceContext))
                                    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                                    .UseSerilog()
                                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                                    .UseServiceFabricIntegration(listener, ServiceFabricIntegrationOptions.None)
                                    .UseUrls(url)
                                    .Build();
                            }))
            };
        }

        private IConfigurationRoot GetAppSettings()
        {
            return new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile(AppSettingsFilename)
                .Build();
        }
    }
}
```

**Using the Logger within a controller**
Because the ILogger instance is configured as a Dependency Injected instance it can simply be accessed within your Controller classes like any other dependency e.g.

```
    [Authorize]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class UserController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly IUserService _userService;
        private readonly ILogger<UserController> _logger;

        public UserController(IUserService userService, ILogger<UserController> logger)
        {
            _userService = userService;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost("authenticate")]
        public IActionResult Authenticate([FromBody] DtoAuthenticateRequest request)
        {
            // Adding log entries
            _logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, "Here is a log entry");

            // Some code in here
            return Ok(response);
        }
    }
```

I got very sidetracked with the `ServiceEventSource.cs` class but with the usage of Serilog I have now ignored this aspect of the project template.

If you wish to output your logs to other data consumers or simply into different formats then just review the Serilog website [here](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Provided-Sinks) for a complete list of the Sinks available, with Application Insights being one of the many.

Comment: Developing my SF solution I came to the same conclusions as @Andrew Holloway-Breward. I've found `ServiceEventSource` rather confusing. And I used `Serilog` logging to file instead, with no issues. So I can recommend this approach as well.

Comment: I'm using logging similar to yours and with Service Fabric I can't achieve debug verbosity (max. up to  information level). With the same setup on a standalone web app I don't have any problem...

Comment: Hi @Marko we abandoned Service Fabric some months ago and moved everything into Azure Functions so I no longer have my setup as it was however the control over verbosity is simply managed by the MinimumLevel setting in the appSettings.json file or on each Sink there is a RestrictedToMinimumLevel setting. Without knowing a bit more about what your problem is it is quite difficult to second guess what your issue could be. Are you outputting to AzureBlobStorage? Do you get any content in the log files? Have you tried debugging serilog using Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable method?

Comment: No I'm writing lof to a file on file share. The code in the standalone web app is identical to those in the SF service web app, so the settings are the same.